# Finding the limit of $\left(\sum\limits_{k=2}^n\frac1{k\log k}\right)-\left(\log \log n\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, euler-maclaurin

There is this well known limit:

$$\lim_n \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k -\log n=\gamma$$

Where $\log$ is the natural logarithm and $\gamma$ is Euler constant.

I was wondering if my similar situation yelds to a similar result:

$$\lim_n \sum_{k=2}^n \frac 1{k\log k}-\log \log n=?$$

I know there is a formula (always due to Euler) which can be used in those situations but I can't see if there is a way to put the result in "closed form" rather than having only an approximation (supposing the limit exists and is finite at first)

Comment: @Arthur I fear that too, any idea on how to prove it?

Comment: $\int_2^\infty (\frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor \log \lfloor x \rfloor}- \frac{1}{x \log x})dx$ does converge @Arthur

Comment: A quick Mathematica computation:
The value for $f(n) = \sum_{k=2}^n 1/(k\ln k) - \ln\ln n$ with $n = 10'000$ to $100'000$ with step of $10'000$. 
$\{0.794684,0.794681,0.79468,0.79468,0.79468,0.794679,0.794679,0.794679,0.794679,0.794679 \}$. Looks like convergence to me.

Comment: Nice, I always fear the worst but I guess this is not the case!

Comment: The convergence can be derived from the fact the series is decreasing and a bound which can be found by comparing to integrals. (The decreasing part might prove tedious though). However, I doubt there is any closed form expression for the limit, given that there is none for the classical limit $\lim \sum \frac 1k - \log(n)$ (this is just the definition of $\gamma$).

Comment: I assume the OP was referring to the Euler-Maclaurin formula, which quickly proves this converges with bounds.

Comment: $$\lim_{t\to \infty } \, \left(\int_2^t \frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) \log \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)} \, dx-\log (\log (t))\right)=-\log \left(\log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)$$ can prove that the OP limit exists and is finite?

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2413022), this constant is evaluated to $49$ places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit long for a comment, not really a finished answer.

---

More generally, consider

$$I(s)=\int_2^\infty\left(\frac1{\lfloor x\rfloor^s\ln\lfloor x\rfloor}-\frac1{x^s\ln(x)}\right)~\mathrm dx$$

By differentiating under the integral,

$$I'(s)=\int_2^\infty\left(\frac1{\lfloor x\rfloor^s}-\frac1{x^s}\right)~\mathrm dx$$

Which may be shown to equal

$$I'(s)=\begin{cases}\zeta(s)-1+\frac1{1-s}2^{1-s},&s\ne1\\\gamma,&s=1\end{cases}$$

And so,

\begin{align}I(1)&=\int_1^\infty\left(1-\zeta(s)-\frac{2^{1-s}}{1-s}\right)~\mathrm ds\\&=\gamma-1+\lim_{b\to\infty}\big(b-\zeta^{\star}(b)\big)-\lim_{a\to0^+}\big(\ln(-a\ln(2))-\zeta^\star(a+1)\big)\end{align}

where

$$\zeta^\star(s)=\int_t^s\zeta(x)~\mathrm dx,\quad t>1$$

and $\operatorname{Ei}(s)$ is the [exponential integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html).

...not really sure if this integral/limit is doable...

Answer (score 3):

Using $\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)\ge\frac1{x+1}$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
&\left(\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac1{k\log(k)}-\log(\log(n+1))\right)-\left(\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k\log(k)}-\log(\log(n))\right)\\
&=\frac1{(n+1)\log(n+1)}-\log\left(\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}\right)\\
&\le\frac1{(n+1)\log(n+1)}-\log\left(\frac{\log(n)+\frac1{n+1}}{\log(n)}\right)\\
&=\frac1{(n+1)\log(n+1)}-\log\left(1+\frac1{(n+1)\log(n)}\right)\\
&\le\frac1{(n+1)\log(n+1)}-\frac1{(n+1)\log(n)+1}\\
&\le\frac1{(n+1)\left(\log(n)+\frac1{n+1}\right)}-\frac1{(n+1)\log(n)+1}\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k\log(k)}-\log(\log(n))
$$
is decreasing. Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k\log(k)}-\log(\log(n))
&\ge\int_2^{n+1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x\log(x)}-\log(\log(n))\\
&=\log(\log(n+1))-\log(\log(2))-\log(\log(n))\\[9pt]
&\ge-\log(\log(2))
\end{align}
$$
is bounded below,

Thus,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k\log(k)}-\log(\log(n))\right)
$$
exists.

In fact, in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2413022), this limit is computed to $49$ places using the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula):
$$
0.7946786454528994022038979620651495140649995908828
$$

Comment: Hm... can moderators post answers to closed questions?

Comment: No, but sometimes if you've had your answer open from before the question is closed, it posts anyway.

Comment: Hm, okay. Strange that the question was closed 4 hours before you posted your answer.

Comment: I had the answer open for a long time. I often take a long time answering; kinda busy irl.

Comment: :P Okay. Was just curious.