# Determine $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2\ln(2)} + \frac{1}{3\ln(3)} + \dots + \frac{1}{n\ln(n)} - \ln(\ln(n))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

The problem is stated as following:

> Determine $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2\ln(2)} + \frac{1}{3\ln(3)} + \dots + \frac{1}{n\ln(n)} - \ln(\ln(n))$

**My attempt:**

First of all, I try to simplify the expression to:

$\displaystyle L = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left [\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k\ln(k)} \right ]- \ln(\ln(n))$

We notice that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k\ln(k)}$ can be approximated to $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_ {2}^{n}\frac{dx}{x\ln(x)} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \ln(\ln(n))-\ln(\ln(2))$

Plugging that into our first expression we get:

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} -\ln(\ln(2)) = -\ln(\ln(2))$. Hence:

$$\boxed{L = -\ln(\ln(2))}$$

**Comments:**

I don't know whether it's okay to approximate the series with this limit without stating whether the integral is greater than or equal to the first expression. If I had to do that, then I'd also have to show that the expression is greater than 0, in order to use the limit comparision test.

I'd be glad if you could add any comments on what (if any) steps in my solution went wrong, and why in that case.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that you would need to show that the error term coming from the approximation tends to zero as $n\to +\infty$, since $$
\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{1}{{k\log k}}}  - \log \log n = \left[ {\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{1}{{k\log k}}}  - \int_2^n {\frac{{dt}}{{t\log t}}} } \right] - \log \log 2.
$$ Thus, $L=-\log\log 2$ if and only if the expression in the brackets tends to $0$.

Comment: @Gary Oh okay, I see what to do now. Thanks!!!

Comment: Your claimed value for the limit approximates $0.37$, but the $n=1000$ and $n=2000$ cases both approximates $0.79$, and that leads me to suspect the limit is different.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584319/what-is-known-about-the-double-log-eulers-constant-lim-n-to-infty-sum). It seems that the limit cannot be written in a simple way with other known constants.

Comment: @Tanamas Where is the question coming from? And can you precise what *determine* means in the context of your question?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: That looks like a good duplicate target to me.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net It's from a textbook we use in our school :)